# Is there a way to iteratively add plots to Animation.FuncAnimation()?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, animation

I'm working on my master thesis right now and need to animate a high number of points moving. Those points will be representing predators and prey. The number of predators and preys should be changeable and probably around 500 each. For now i hard coded the animation function with 3 predators and 1 prey. is there a way to do it iteratively (e.g for 500 predators and 200 preys)?

EDIT: In google colab the animation is stretched is there a way to make it a proper square?

Thanks in advance!

My code so far (just have random movement for p&p so code is smaller):

```
import matplotlib
import random

import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot
from matplotlib import animation
from matplotlib import rc
rc('animation', html='jshtml')

max_t=200                 # max experiment time
num_pred = 3              # number of predators
num_prey = 1              # number of prey

pred_pos = np.zeros((2*num_pred, max_t))        # initializing x and y positions for pred based on time
prey_pos = np.zeros((2*num_prey, max_t))        # initializing x and y positions for prey based on time
# [pred1_x1, pred1_x2, pred1_x3,...
#  pred1_y1, pred1_y2, pred1_y3,...
#  pred2_x1, pred2_x2, pred2_x3,...
#  pred2_y1, pred2_y2, pred2_y3,...]


for i in range(2*num_pred):
  pred_pos[i][0] = pred_pos[i][0] + random.uniform(-1, 1)
  for j in range(max_t-1):
    pred_pos[i][j] = pred_pos[i][j-1] + random.uniform(-1, 1)       # random movement

for i in range(2*num_prey):
  prey_pos[i][0] = prey_pos[i][0] + random.uniform(-1, 1)
  for j in range(max_t-1):
    prey_pos[i][j] = prey_pos[i][j-1] + random.uniform(-1, 1)

#print(pred_pos)
#print(prey_pos)


fig=pyplot.figure()
ax = pyplot.axes(xlim=(-10, 10), ylim=(-10, 10))

pred_circle1=pyplot.Circle((pred_pos[0,0],pred_pos[1,0]),0.3,fc='b')
pred_circle2=pyplot.Circle((pred_pos[2,0],pred_pos[3,0]),0.3,fc='b')
pred_circle3=pyplot.Circle((pred_pos[4,0],pred_pos[5,0]),0.3,fc='b')

prey_circle1=pyplot.Circle((prey_pos[0,0],prey_pos[1,0]),0.3,fc='r')


def init():
    pred_circle1.center=(pred_pos[0,0],pred_pos[1,0])       # pred_circle1.center=(x,y)
    pred_circle2.center=(pred_pos[2,0],pred_pos[3,0])
    pred_circle3.center=(pred_pos[4,0],pred_pos[5,0])
    prey_circle1.center=(prey_pos[0,0],prey_pos[1,0])
    ax.add_patch(pred_circle1)
    ax.add_patch(pred_circle2)
    ax.add_patch(pred_circle3)
    ax.add_patch(prey_circle1)
    return pred_circle1, pred_circle2, pred_circle3, prey_circle1,

def animate(i):
    pred_circle1.center=(pred_pos[0,i],pred_pos[1,i])
    pred_circle2.center=(pred_pos[2,i],pred_pos[3,i])
    pred_circle3.center=(pred_pos[4,i],pred_pos[5,i])
    prey_circle1.center=(prey_pos[0,i],prey_pos[1,i])
    return pred_circle1, pred_circle2, pred_circle3, prey_circle1,


anim=animation.FuncAnimation(fig,animate, init_func=init,frames=max_t,blit=True)

anim
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve it is by knowing that your first add all the predators, then all the preys. So, `ax.patches` contains an ordered list of patches, and you can loop over them to update their positions:

```py
import matplotlib
import random

import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot
from matplotlib import animation

max_t=200                 # max experiment time
num_pred = 15              # number of predators
num_prey = 4              # number of prey

pred_pos = np.zeros((2*num_pred, max_t))        # initializing x and y positions for pred based on time
prey_pos = np.zeros((2*num_prey, max_t))        # initializing x and y positions for prey based on time
# [pred1_x1, pred1_x2, pred1_x3,...
#  pred1_y1, pred1_y2, pred1_y3,...
#  pred2_x1, pred2_x2, pred2_x3,...
#  pred2_y1, pred2_y2, pred2_y3,...]


for i in range(2*num_pred):
    pred_pos[i][0] = pred_pos[i][0] + random.uniform(-1, 1)
    for j in range(max_t-1):
        pred_pos[i][j] = pred_pos[i][j-1] + random.uniform(-1, 1)       # random movement

for i in range(2*num_prey):
    prey_pos[i][0] = prey_pos[i][0] + random.uniform(-1, 1)
    for j in range(max_t-1):
        prey_pos[i][j] = prey_pos[i][j-1] + random.uniform(-1, 1)


fig=pyplot.figure()
ax = pyplot.axes(xlim=(-10, 10), ylim=(-10, 10))

# add an arbitrary number of preys and predators
for i in range(num_pred):
    p = pyplot.Circle((pred_pos[2 * i, 0], pred_pos[2 * i + 1, 0]),0.3,fc='b')
    ax.add_patch(p)
for i in range(num_prey):
    p = pyplot.Circle((prey_pos[2 * i, 0], prey_pos[2 * i + 1, 0]),0.3,fc='r')
    ax.add_patch(p)

def animate(i):
    # update positions
    for k in range(num_pred):
        ax.patches[k].center=(pred_pos[2*k,i],pred_pos[2*k+1,i])
    for k in range(num_prey):
        ax.patches[num_pred + k].center=(prey_pos[2*k,i],prey_pos[2*k+1,i])

anim=animation.FuncAnimation(fig,animate, frames=max_t)
pyplot.show()
```